# Chips input layout without library

Tags: android, kotlin

[image: implemented]

I have implemented till attached image. I want to place search box next to chips.

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/chipRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtSearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:hint="Search"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/chipRecyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
       />
```

and for recyclerview i have used Flexboxlayout manager. If i place constraints next to recyclerview. chipsview does not render horizontally.
Can anyone give any idea how to modify it without using any library or material theme ?
any help is appreciated .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to display the `EditText` at the right of the `chipRecyclerView ` or after its last element?

Comment: yes, thats correct, after last element of recyclerview.but recyclerview should be scrollable if more elements.

Comment: Ok, can you post your recycler view adapter? You can do it by implementing multiple view types in it.

Comment: but i dont want edittext to be scrollable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i got the answer by following [this link](https://github.com/DoodleScheduling/android-material-chips). Hopefully it help someone.